# Material design multiple auto complete angular 2 / 4

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I use the following library:
https://material.angular.io

I see that there is an autocomplete function for angular 2 material. How about multi auto complete? for instance I would like to allow user to pick more than 1 states in the autocomplete textbox. Thanks.

I want to make it looks like in the domain.com.au website as per the screenshot below: And the best thing is if it's running out of space, it will expand the textbox vertically (make it higher) and becomes multiline.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solution is what you're looking for but you can combine the classic autocomplete with Angular Material [chips](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview). In the `(onSelectionChange)` event assign the values you want to the data structure bound to the chips list.